# Translate from nginx to apache

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

Nginx:

```
server {

listen 2083 ssl;
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?ip=$remote_addr break; 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host                  $http_host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
access_log off;
log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:2083>
<Location /
ProxyPass http://localhost:2082/ retry= 0
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:2082/
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyErrorOverride Off
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This part in nginx:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?ip=$remote_addr break;
```

I want to do exactly that for Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you still need more directives to correctly set up TLS - I'm assuming you omitted them for brevity :-). See [this](https://cipherlist.eu/) and [this](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) for pointers on how to do that.

```
Listen 2083 https

<VirtualHost *:2083>

ProxyPass http://localhost:2082/ retry= 0
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:2082/
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyErrorOverride Off

# Disables logging for this vHost
ErrorLog /dev/null
CustomLog /dev/null common

RewriteEngine On

# Redirects with 302, the L breaks from rule processing
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR} [R,L]

<Proxy http://localhost:2082/>
  Require all granted
  # Sets the X-Real-IP header.
  RequestHeader set X-Real-IP "%{REMOTE_ADDR}"
</Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: got a few errors in apache:  Unrecognized header format %  & Invalid ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch parameter. Parameter must be in the form 'key=value'.  Also when you open https://myserverip:2083/  it redirects to https://myserverip:2083/?ip=myip     Nginx didnt do this.